# Training a katago go ai with 2 moves in a row

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Go is an ancient game of great strategy and depth, and in recent years the rise of artificial intelligence such as AlphaGo and KataGo has led to astounding achievements in the Go world. Now, you want to train a KataGo AI capable of making two moves in a row, and you want it to adapt to the Flying Dagger rule on the Wildfox Go platform.payable

Comment: Can someone train one for me for a fee?